# Using wordpress built in thickbox without plugin

Tags: php, jquery, html, css, wordpress

I am trying to use the built in thickbox in wordpress in my theme. I am trying to make it so all pictures that I add through the admin automatically have the thickbox function. I tried putting this in the functions.php but it did not work:

```
function fb_add_thickbox($content){
$content = preg_replace('/<a(.*?)href="(.*?).(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|bmp|ico)"(.*?)><img/U', '<a$1href="$2.$3" $4 class="thickbox"><img', $content);
return $content;
}
add_filter('the_content', 'fb_add_thickbox', 2);
```

Comment: that code works internally? I mean, the_content filter run on internal views, but I think it probably doesn't work in the home page ( except if you force to run it )

Comment: Have inserted javascript and css for thichkbox ?

Comment: you have to enqueeue the thickbox scripts before, because it is only include in the admin section of the website

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that your code is actually working - (is your markup actually getting filtered?) - this will fail, as thickbox has not been activated. You must manually inject it:

As @Alexcp noted - you must register and enqueue the javascript and css manually (outside of the admin section). In addition to your preg_replace function, add the following to your template's `Functions.php`.

```
// register scripts 
if (! function_exists(thickbox_register){
function thickbox_register() {
    wp_deregister_script( 'jquery' );
    wp_register_script( 'jquery','http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6/jquery.min.js');
    wp_register_script( 'thickbox', 'path to thickbox'.thickbox.js, 'jquery');
    }  
}   
add_action('init', 'thickbox_register');

//print the now registered scripts 
if (! function_exists(thickbox_enqueue){
function thickbox_enqueue() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery' );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'thickbox' );
    }  
}
add_action('wp_print_scripts', 'thickbox_enqueue');

// do the same for css 
if (! function_exists(thickbox_style_enqueue){
function thickbox_style_enqueue() {
    wp_register_style( 'thickbox', 'path to css'.thickbox.css );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'thickbox' );
    }  
}
add_action('wp_print_styles', 'thickbox_style_enqueue');
```

Note that paths can be obtained [several ways](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/bloginfo) - but something like `bloginfo('url');` should get you started.

If you still have problems, use FireBug or something like it to ensure that **thickbox is getting registered properly** in the jquery object of the DOM.

Hope that helps

Comment: please update your code its have syntax error, you have forget to add another `")"` of `IF` expresssion

Answer (score 2):

This one worked for me

```
<?php add_thickbox(); ?>
<div id="my-content-id" style="display:none;">
 <p>
      This is my hidden content! It will appear in ThickBox when the link is clicked.
 </p>
</div>

<a href="#TB_inline?width=600&height=550&inlineId=my-content-id" 
class="thickbox">View my inline content!</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

add this to your functions.php file in your theme:

```
<?php
// Adds thickbox to all images with a link inside of $content.
// Uses the title attribute in the Media Library.
add_filter('the_content', 'brentini_addthickboxclass');
function brentini_addthickboxclass($content) {
add_thickbox();
$pattern[0] = "/<a(.*?)href=('|\")(.*?).(bmp|gif|jpeg|jpg|png)('|\")(.*?)>/i";
$replacement[0] = '<a$1href=$2$3.$4$5 class="thickbox">';
$pattern[1] = "/(<a href=)('|\")([^\>]*?)(\.bmp|\.gif|\.jpg|\.jpeg|\.png)('|\")([^\>]*?)(>)(.*?) title=('|\")(.*?)('|\")(.*?)(<\/a>)/i";
$replacement[1] = '$1$2$3$4$5$6 title=$9$10$11$7$8 title=$9$10$11$12$13';
$pattern[2] = "/(<a href=)('|\")([^\>]*?)(\.bmp|\.gif|\.jpg|\.jpeg|\.png)('|\")([^\>]*?) title=([^\>]*?) title=([^\>]*?)(>)(.*?)(<\/a>)/i";
$replacement[2] = '$1$2$3$4$5$6 title=$7$9$10$11';
$content = preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $content);
return $content;
}
```

It will work flawlessly if you do it exactly like this. There is no need to add all of those calls that others have mentioned. It isn't at all necessary since WordPress natively includes jquery and thickbox for use on the backend. So add_thickbox() is all you need to call thickbox in your theme. The rest of the script simply adds class="thickbox" to any image inside $content and uses the title attribute from the WordPress Media Library.

If you are interested in a script which includes this plus Thickbox support for galleries with navigation as well, check it out at [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/bijiUztb).

For a more simplified version that does not include navigation, [this one at pastebin](http://pastebin.com/aEEwtEmW) uses jquery to add the thickbox class to galleries.

Answer (score -1):

Some easy way, wordpress has already contained `thickbox.js` in it's script folder.

So just open `wp-include/script-loader.php`

find the line from `function print_head_scripts()`,

Add `$wp_scripts->do_items( 'thickbox' );` after`$wp_scripts->do_items( 'l10n' );`

Then refresh you page, you will see the `thickbox.js` have already include in your `header part`, then only add `class="thickbox"` in your `<a> tag`, you can call the thickbox perfectly.

Comment: This is really bad practice, because this require changes to the core.